# Java OpenGL(JOGL) Object Arrays and FloatBuffers

Tags: java, pointers, opengl, vector, floatbuffer

I’m trying to find a may to minimize memory allocation and garbage collection in a Java OpenGL (JOGL) application.  I am porting some C/C++/C# OpenGL project to Java as a learning exercise.  One thing I am running into is the lack of pointers in Java and the allocation of objects and GC of them as the application runs.  In C/C++/C# I can get the applications to startup and simply run without allocating any additional memory or objects by passing references around but in Java it seems my designs are incompatible.

As these designs have evolved they are using higher level objects.  In C they were structs for Vectors and Matrices and in C++/C# classes.  These all essentially boil down to arrays of bytes in memory.  Which are then cast in one way or another to float[] for OpenGL calls or object arrays internally within the application so I can us object based operations like operator overloading, add and multiply, or property accessing for example.  Anyone working with OpenGL probably sees what I am doing.  This way I allocate everything on load and simply pass the data around.

Java has thrown me for some loops.  It appears I cannot cast data back and forth thus I keep creating lots of data and the GC comes by and does it work.  This is noticeable by resources being consumed and cleaned up and a noticeable stutter during the application run.  I have alleviated some of this by creating FloatBuffers in addition to VectorXf arrays for my geometry data and pass the FloatBuffer down to OpenGL.  But when I need to update Vector data I have to recopy the data back to the float buffer.  This also means I am storing double the data and incurring the overhead of the floatbuffer fills.

I’d like to hear how others are dealing with these issues.  I’d like to keep the higher order objects for the functionality built in but be able to pass the data to OpenGL.  Are my designs simply incompatible with Java?  Do I need to move to FloatBuffers exclusively?  How does one pass component data into a higher order object without the penalty of object creation.  So many OpenGL applications exist that I suspect there is some ‘magic’ to utilize either the same buffer for float[] and Object[] or allocate contiguous block for object data and pass a reference to OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

The driving force in managing your OpenGL data is that you don't want to be responsible for the memory containing the geometry or textures.  The use of `float[]` or even FloatBuffers should only be for the purpose of transferring geometry data into OpenGL buffer objects.  Once you've created an OpenGL buffer and copied the data to it, you no longer need to keep a copy in your JVM.  On virtually all modern hardware this will cause the data to be retained on the video card itself, completely outside of the JVM.

Ideally, if most of your geometry is static, you can copy it to OpenGL buffers at startup time and never have to manage it directly again.  If you're dealing with a lot of dynamic geometry, then you're still going to be having to transfer data back and forth to the OpenGL driver.  In this case, you probably want to maintain a pool of FloatBuffers that can act as ferries for moving the data between your code generating or discovering the changing geometry, and the driver.  FloatBuffers are unavoidable because OpenGL expects data in a given format, which is going to be different than the internal representation of the data in the JVM, but at the very least you don't need to be keeping a separate FloatBuffer around for every set of data you have.

Comment: Thats about where I am at.  Created VBOs for everything and pass down to GL then remove the buffer.  Strange thing is 1 out of 5 times the application will core dump at glBufferData.  Its like the code is moveing to the glBufferData call before the float buffers are full or a null somewhere.  All I do after it crashes, at startup, is start again and it works.  Still working that annyoing behavior.  For the dynamic content, screen font output, I keep a buffe around to ferry as you stated the data to hardware via glDrawArrays.  Everything else is static thus far.

Comment: FloatBuffers are something of a pain.  They maintain an internal pointer to the 'current spot' in the buffer, so that it's easy to append to them.  Most crashes I've encountered in dealing with them involve forgetting to reset the pointer back to 0 before sending it to GL, which means that OpenGL will start reading from the middle or end of the buffer, and potentially stray into uninitialized memory.  Other potential sources of errors involve miscalculating the number of bytes available in the buffer, which you need to pass into glBufferData.

Comment: All the buffers are set to position(0) before the glBufferData starts.  Its also wierd that it only happens once in a while.  Same code run to run.  Size, maybe but I am actually directAllocate() ByteBuffers asFloatBuffer so my size are calculated in bytes so I'm 99% sure they are accurate.  Its a port from C like langs so the math is the same, i'd hope...

Comment: Hi Jherico, so basically one should keep a fixed FloatBuffer (or a pool) and then modifying its size according the needings to transfer data to gpu? @user2811897 did you find your bug?

Answer (score 0):

My experience:
I was using FloatBuffers for only transferring data, but I found that this was really performance killing for dynamic meshes because I had to transform my Vec arrays to FloatBuffers everytime I change my meshes. Now I got rid of my vec arrays and only use FloatBuffers persistently through my mesh classes, less elegant to handle them but much faster. So I would advise you to keep & update all your geometry data with FloatBuffers